# LookUp AMPscript fails when doing a look up on sending DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

When I try to SET a variable using a lookup from the Data Extension that we're deploying to, it doesn't work... when I set the value by placing just the field name it works fine.

`SET @Currency = LookUp('MYDEName','currency','emailaddress',emailaddr)` FAILS

`SET @currency = currency` WORKS

What gives?  I've never encountered this before

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to perform a [lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) if your `Currency` field is on the sendable data extension?

Your syntax is correct. Check that your DE names and field names are correct: `MYDEName`, `currency`, `emailaddress`

Try setting the emailaddr as a variable. Then you can hard-code the value to check that it is working correctly.

```
%%[
set @emailaddr = emailaddr
SET @Currency = LookUp('MYDEName','currency','emailaddress',@emailaddr)
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Jackson - Do I need to the lookup? No, but I like to keep my coding consistent as we are doing several lookups.  I'm still unsure why it's not working though.

Comment: It seems unnecessary to perform a lookup if it's in the sendable data extension. Have you verified that the field names are correct and the email address is in the data extension?

Comment: @GeorgeRosedale - doing unnecessary lookups will cause increased processing and is very inefficient and most certainly not best practice. Also, you will be doing a lookup on a DE that is currently being used (in the email send). I feel like it may be failing as that specific row is 'locked' while it is processing the email.

Comment: @Gortonington - I have a feeling the db being locked is the culprit here.